# NodeJS-C interface

Tags: c, node.js, node.js-addon, node-ffi

I am trying to figure out how to pass data between a C library and a NodeJS module. 
Would I be able to do so via the NodeFFI module?

Or will I have to write my own NodeJS addon to develop a C-NodeJS interface?

Answer (score 5):

The `node-ffi` documentation states:

> `node-ffi` is a Node.js addon for loading and calling dynamic libraries using pure JavaScript. It can be used to create bindings to native libraries without writing any C++ code.

You just need to access libraries as stated in `node-ffi` and the pass results elsewhere. In their source, they have an example. Assuming they're in the same directory:

File `factorial.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t factorial(int max) {
  int i = max;
  uint64_t result = 1;

  while (i >= 2) {
    result *= i--;
  }

  return result;
}
```

File `factorial.js`:

```
//load the ffi module
var ffi = require('ffi');

//include the function
var libfactorial = ffi.Library('./libfactorial', {
  'factorial': [ 'uint64', [ 'int' ] ]
});

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Arguments: ' + process.argv[0] + ' ' + process.argv[1] + ' <max>');
  process.exit();
};

//usage of the function
var output = libfactorial.factorial(parseInt(process.argv[2]));

console.log('Your output: ' + output);
```

Using the module, the C file is loaded with this:

```
var libfactorial = ffi.Library('./libfactorial', {
  'factorial': [ 'uint64', [ 'int' ] ]
});
```

and then accessed like this:

```
//process.argv are the command line arguments
var argument = parseInt(process.argv[2]);
var output = libfactorial.factorial(argument);
```